# How to open a specific preferences page in Android?

Tags: android, android-preferences

When creating preferences, there is a standard preference header showing the categories General, Data & Sync and Notifications. The preferences are kept in XML files.

How could I open the General category immediately instead of opening the preference header which shows the categories? I couldn't find this.

Comment: 'there is a standard preference header showing the categories General, Data & Sync and Notifications.'. ?? Where? I have never seen that.

Comment: simulate a clik event on the categ that should open. clik-handler drills down & updates the view

Comment: @greenapps When right clicking new -> Activity -> SettingsActivity some default categories are made as well as settings.

Comment: @RobertRowntree unfortunately it's not that easy with the default SettingsActivity. There is no visible onClick function and it seems to be using fragments.

Comment: https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android/blob/master/src/com/google/sample/cast/refplayer/settings/CastPreference.java  is sample 'extends PreferenceActivity'  if that helps figure out how to trigger event that drills down into a PrefCagegory's detl content...